# Angular Update View

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I'm developing an angular application with pagination. My component holds a list of all employees. When it initializes, it gets data from the service . Once this data comes back, the list gets updated and I use it in my paging method. At this point, my application state has changed so I will want to update the view. Everything works good but with delay. I see changes only after F5.  I don't understand, how can I tell Angular to update the view in particular moment. To ensure that a task is performed before a route can be activated I use resolver, but it helps only for the first render. I understand, that problem is with async data, but I don't understand, how to fix it. Please, help me to solve this problem.

My component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "paTable",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "table.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["table.component.css"]
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit{
    private allEmployees: Employee[];
    pager: any =  {};
    pagedItems: any[];
    constructor(private model: Model, private paginationService: PaginationService){
        console.log('constructor');
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.allEmployees = this.model.getAllEmployees();
        console.log(this.allEmployees);
        this.setPage(1);
    }

    deleteEmployee(key: number) {
        this.model.deleteEmployee(key);
    }

    setPage(page: number){
        console.log(page)
        if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }

        // get pager object from service
        this.pager = this.paginationService.getPagination(this.allEmployees.length, page);
        console.log(this.allEmployees.length);
        console.log(this.pager.startIndex);
        // get current page of items
        this.pagedItems = (this.model.getAllEmployees()).slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.pageSize + 1);
        console.log(this.pagedItems);
    }
}
```

My service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Model{
    private employees: Employee[] = new Array<Employee>();
    private departments: Department[] = new Array<Department>();

    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource){
        console.log('model');
        this.dataSource.getEmployeesData().subscribe(data => this.employees = data);
        this.dataSource.getDepsData().subscribe(data => this.departments = data);
    }

    getAllEmployees(): Employee[]{
        return this.employees;
    }

    getAllDeps(): Department[]{

        return this.departments;
    }

    getEmployee(id: number): Employee{
        return this.employees.find(e => e.id == id);
    }


    saveEmployee(employee: Employee){
        if(employee.id == 0 || employee.id == null){
            this.dataSource.saveEmployee(employee).subscribe(e => {employee.id = e.insertId; this.employees.push(employee)});
        }else{
            this.dataSource.updateEmployee(employee).subscribe(() => {
                let index = this.employees.findIndex(e => e.id == employee.id);
                this.employees.splice(index,1,employee);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My template:

```
<tbody>    
        <tr *ngFor="let item of pagedItems; let i = index">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
            <td [ngSwitch] = "item.isActive">
                <span *ngSwitchCase ="1">Yes</span>
                <span *ngSwitchDefault>No</span>
            </td>
            <td [ngSwitch] = "item.emp_depID">
                <span *ngSwitchCase = "1">HR</span>
                <span *ngSwitchCase = "2">Tech</span>
                <span *ngSwitchCase = "3">Finance</span>
                <span *ngSwitchDefault>No data</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" (click)="deleteEmployee(item.id)">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" [routerLink]="['/form', 'edit', item.id]">
                    Edit
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

My resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModelResolver{

    constructor(private model: Model, private dataSource: DataSource, 
                private messages: MessageService){

    }
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Employee[]>{
        if (this.model.getAllEmployees().length == 0){
            this.messages.reportMessage(new Message("Loading data..."));
            return this.dataSource.getEmployeesData(); 
        }
    }
}
```

app.routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
                            { path: "form/:mode/:id", component:FormComponent }, 
                            { path: "form/:mode", component:FormComponent},
                            { path: "", component: TableComponent, resolve:{model:ModelResolver} },
                        ]
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

datasource:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataSource{

    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(URL) private url: string){
        console.log('datasource')
    }

    getEmployeesData(): Observable<Employee[]>{
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, `${this.url}employeeslist`);
    }
    getDepsData(): Observable<Department[]>{
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, `${this.url}depslist`);
    }
    saveEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<Response>{
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, `${this.url}save`, employee);
    }
    updateEmployee(employee:Employee): Observable<Employee>{
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Put, `${this.url}${employee.id}`, employee);
    }
    deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<Employee>{
        return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Delete, `${this.url}${id}`);
    }

    private sendRequest(method: RequestMethod, url: string, body?: Employee){
        return this.http.request(new Request({
            method: method,
            url: url,
            body: body
        })).map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: ngFor directive has its own change detection mechanism, as DeborahK said when pagedItems changes list should be updated itself.

Comment: In looking at this code ... it is just confusing. It appears that you are retrieving the data in the resolver, but then not using that data and instead getting the data again in the service? Normally a service does not subscribe. It is recommended that the subscribe be moved as close to the UI as possible. And the component should be getting the data from the resolver, not from the service? Or the resolver can be removed because it is not adding any functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code resolver is used to ensure that a task is performed before a route can be activated. When the resolve method is called in the ModelResolver class, it checks the number of objects in the data model to determine whether the HTTP request to the server has completed. If there are no objects in the data model, the resolve method returns the Observable from the DataSource. So it prevents the user from seeing the table until the model has been populated with the data from the server. The problem was in the ngOnInit() method I think, because this.model.getAllEmployees(); returns an array of employees and I assign it to the variable and use it in my code. When  ngOnInit() is called, async request hasn't yet completed, and my variable gets old data from the method. New data arrives with some delay, so only after F5, I can see my new results.I deleted ngOnInit() method and uses only my methods. 
Here is my code.

```
@Component({
        selector: "paTable",
        moduleId: module.id,
        templateUrl: "table.component.html",
        styleUrls: ["table.component.css"]
    })
    export class TableComponent{
        employeesPerPage = 10;
        selectedPage = 1;
        totalPages: number;

        constructor(private model: Model){

        }

        getAllEmployees(): Employee[]{
           let pageIndex = (this.selectedPage - 1)*this.employeesPerPage; 
           return this.model.getAllEmployees().slice(pageIndex, pageIndex + this.employeesPerPage);
        }

        getKey(index: number, employee: Employee){
            return employee.id;
        }

        deleteEmployee(key: number) {
            this.model.deleteEmployee(key);
        }
        changePage(newPage: number){
            this.selectedPage = newPage;
        }
        get pageNumbers(): number[]{
            this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.model.getAllEmployees().length/this.employeesPerPage);
            let startPage: number;
            let endPage: number;
            if(this.totalPages <= 10){
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = this.totalPages;            
            }else{
                if(this.selectedPage <= 6){
                    startPage = 1;
                    endPage = 10;
                }else if(this.selectedPage + 4 >= this.totalPages){
                    startPage = this.totalPages-9;
                    endPage = this.totalPages;
                }else{
                    startPage = this.selectedPage - 5;
                    endPage = this.selectedPage + 4;
                }
            }
            return new Array((endPage+1) - startPage).fill(0).map((x,i) => i + startPage);
        }
    }
```

Template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of getAllEmployees(); let i = index; trackBy:getKey">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
            <td [ngSwitch] = "item.isActive">
                <span *ngSwitchCase ="1">Yes</span>
                <span *ngSwitchDefault>No</span>
            </td>
            <td [ngSwitch] = "item.emp_depID">
                <span *ngSwitchCase = "1">HR</span>
                <span *ngSwitchCase = "2">Tech</span>
                <span *ngSwitchCase = "3">Finance</span>
                <span *ngSwitchDefault>No data</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" (click)="deleteEmployee(item.id)">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>    
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" [routerLink]="['/form', 'edit', item.id]">
                    Edit
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

My "model" service looks more like this:

```
private products: IProduct[];

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    if (this.products) {
        return of(this.products);
    }
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productsUrl)
                    .pipe(
                        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
                        tap(data => this.products = data),
                        catchError(this.handleError)
                    );
}
```

When the first request comes in, the `products` property is not yet set so it goes to get the data. For future requests, it returns the previously retrieved list.

In doing it this way, the method is returning an Observable, so a resolver would work. Otherwise the component could subscribe.

So either:

1) Change your service to return an observable.

Subscribe to that observable in the component.

Move the code you want to execute after that data is retrieved to inside the subscribe.

OR

2) Change your service to return an observable

Use a resolver to get the data

Use the resolvers data in the component. That way the data is available as soon as the component is initialized.

For example, consider changing your code as follows:

```
getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    if (this.employees) {
       return of(this.employees);
    }
   return this.dataSource.getEmployeesData();
}
```

And removing the call from the constructor.

Then your component (or your resolver ... not both) can call the `getAllEmployees` method and get back the observable.

For example:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.model.getAllEmployees().subscribe(
          employees => { 
             console.log(employees);
             this.allEmployees = employees;
             this.setPage(1);
          }
    );
}
```

Comment: I've added another part of my code.All http requests I make from datasource.ts. My repository.model gets response from it. And my component gets data from repository.model.

Comment: What is your resolver trying to do? It does not appear that your component is using the data that it retrieves?

Comment: Please, can you tell me how to use data from my resolver?

Comment: I put it in the path and think, that my component uses it

Comment: You aren't injecting the router into your component ... so your component is not referencing the data from the resolver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this to a separate answer because the prior answer was getting too long. In addition to the model service changes I outlined in my prior answer, you can use a resolver's data like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/products/product-detail.component.html'
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = 'Product Detail';
    product: IProduct;
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.product = this.route.snapshot.data['product'];
    }
}
```

Note that I'm injecting in the ActivatedRoute. Then using `this.route.snapshot.data` to read the data retrieved by the resolver.

In your route configuration, you named the data `model`, so your syntax would be:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.allEmployees = this.route.snapshot.data['model'];
    console.log(this.allEmployees);
    this.setPage(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'll try.

Comment: No, your solution didn't work, I've put here my answer.

Comment: I would be interested to hear how this didn't work. It works fine in my application that you can find here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Comment: I've added my answer. I guess that this is the reason of problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The resolve method in my ModelResolver class returns null if there are objects in the model and, since this is neither an Observable nor a Promise, Angular will activate the new route immediately. So, in variable  this.allEmployees = this.route.snapshot.data['model']; I'll have an array of employees with old data after my  deleteEmployee  or saveEmployee requests, because this  HTTP requests to the server hasn't completed at the time of initialization. When refreshing the page, then new results appears.